# Lost Folder On Macbook

Tags: hard-drive

A folder I had on my macbook pro 2017 with a lot of my data recently mysteriously went missing, I couldn't even find it in the trash, whilst I was able to recover a couple of folders in Finder I can't work out how to recover the majority of them.

They contain the downloads for the first half of the semester for uni & I have exams soon & need to find them, & lost a couple of weeks by posting to StackOverflow before having my post removed & being referred here.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Data Recovery** apps like **[EaseUS Data Recovery](https://www.easeus.com/mac/mac-data-recovery/)**.

References:

- [Best Mac Data Recovery Software - EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard for Mac [2020]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xU9ntMbsi4)
- [How to Recover Deleted Files on Mac - EaseUS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYPlb50pZXY)

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: I recommend you to test SSD or HDD health through some apps by this link, then tell us if it's ok: [6 Apps to Check Mac Hard Drive (or SSD) Health](https://www.anysoftwaretools.com/check-mac-hard-drive-health/)

Comment: Thanks, but no luck

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean "Thanks, but no luck"? Some app mentioned in that article reported some error or warning message, if so, for we can help you add it here in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the data was accidentally or 'mysteriously' erased, then the blocks freed up by that are now available to be overwritten by anything else that needs to write to a file. The longer you keep using the machine, the harder the data will be to retrieve.

If your drive is very full [which seems to be the default state for most people's under-specced laptop drives these days] then 2 weeks might just be long enough to have reduced that chance to zero. Even downloading the recovery software to the drive you are attempting to recover from was a bad move.

I'm assuming - as you wouldn't have needed to ask if you did - that you have no backup.
This is precisely why we have backups.

Your next logical step, after having tried & failed with data recovery software, is to boot to Recovery & test the drive to make sure it has no errors.

Investigate re-acquiring the downloads… & buy a backup drive.